# Bootstrap grid different by screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to know if it is possible to manage differently the "col" div depending on screen size.

I explain, on md screen, i set the col div one behinds the others.
But on mobile, i would like to take the last col div that i have in md screen and put it on second position.

Someone already got his problem ?

thanks

Comment: Not sure if bootstrap have this feature, but you can use order property to modify the order of the columns, it only works with flex, so make sure you are using bootstrap with version greater than 4.0

Comment: Post the code so people understand the question